# How add properties to the Vaadin Calendar BasicEvent?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am implementing the Vaadin 7 Calendar and require to display more
event information than is contained in BasicEvent.

Below is some of the code I am using (events are not being displayed
on calendar):
please can you inform me what I need to add/change?
Thank you Steve...

```
public class CalEvent extends BasicEvent {
    private java.lang.String customer = "";
    public CalEvent() {
    }
    public java.lang.String getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }
    public void setCustomer(java.lang.String customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
}

public class EvtProvider extends BasicEventProvider {
    public void addEvent(CalEvent event) {
        super.addEvent(event);
    }
    public void removeEvent(Event event) {
        super.removeEvent(event);
    }
}

public class Mgr {  
    Mgr() {
        cal = new Calendar("My Calendar");
        EvtProvider evtProvider = new EvtProvider();
        cal.setEventProvider(evtProvider);
        List<CalEvent> lst = getCalEvents();
        for (CalEvent ev : lst) {
            cal.addEvent(ev);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"more event information than is contained in BasicEvent."

For example?

BasicEvent can display a lot of content in event or Event description.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRlN4.png